# Add a new field collection item to an existing field collection

Tags: 8, entities

I have 1 field collection

Field collection: CKT Info child2
  machine name: field_ckt_info_child2

In that have 2 fields:

Field1: English CKT child2
  machine name: field_eng

Field2: Maths CKT Child2
  Machine name: field_maths_ckt_child2

I have set field setting "unlimited" to this field collection. Now I just want to add new field collection item in existing Field collection(CKT Info child2) programmatically. I have tried below code but it's not creating new field collection item. [image: FC Image]

```
function createFC()  {
   $field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_maths_ckt_child2'));
   $field_collection_item->setHostEntity($node);
   $field_collection_item->set('field_maths_ckt_child2', "SET SUCCESS");
   $field_collection->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try code:

```
<?php

use Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

[....]

$node = Node::load(1);

$field_collection_items = $node->field_ckt_info_child2;
$fieldCollectionList = $field_collection_items;
if (count($fieldCollectionList)) {
 //update 
  $field_collection_item = FieldCollectionItem::load($fieldCollectionList[0]->value);
}
else {
  //create new fieldconlection
  $field_collection_item = FieldCollectionItem::create(
    [
      'field_name' => 'field_ckt_info_child2',
    ]
  );
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity($node);
  $field_collection_item->set('field_eng', 'HELLO');
  $field_collection_item->set('field_maths_ckt_child2', 'WORLD');
  $node->field_ckt_info_child2[] = ['field_collection_item' => $field_collection_item];
}

$node->save();
```

Comment: To make it more explicit: The error in the code used from the OP is not initializing `$node` before using it.