# Programmatically add field collection items to a node

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a node with a Field Collection [field_videos]. I would like to be able to progrmatically load a node and add field collection items. The field collection contains the following fields:

- field_video_url
- field_video_title

How can I achieve this in Drupal 8? The few examples I've seen online are for Drupal 8.1 or 8.2 and don't seem to work in the latest version of Drupal.

My code currently looks like this:

```
$field_collection_item = FieldCollectionItem::create([
        'field_name' => 'field_videos',
]);
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity($node);
$field_collection_item->set('field_video_title', 'This is my Title');
$field_collection_item->save();
```

This gives the error: "Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem->setHostEntity()"

Comment: As this question is about code, you should show the code you wrote, or the code you found, so far.

Comment: I have edited my question to include my existing code.

Comment: Is $node set? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268353/add-new-field-collection-item-in-existing-field-collection

Comment: I agree with @4k4: The error message is clearly saying that the parameter passed to `$field_collection_item->setHostEntity()` has not been initialized.